# Understanding long division algorithm

Tags: algorithm, long-integer

I founded some long division code in SphinxAPI class for PHP which divides 64 bit int into two 32 bit integers and used on 32-bit machine when bc library is not available:

```
    // x32, no-bcmath
    $p = max(0, strlen($v) - 13);
    $lo = abs((float)substr($v, $p));
    $hi = abs((float)substr($v, 0, $p));

    $m = $lo + $hi*1316134912.0; // (10 ^ 13) % (1 << 32) = 1316134912
    $q = floor($m/4294967296.0);
    $l = $m - ($q*4294967296.0);
    $h = $hi*2328.0 + $q; // (10 ^ 13) / (1 << 32) = 2328
```

Can you tell me, what algorithm of long division is used here (author called it "fun" in comments)? Or may be it's rewriten expressions of commonly used algorithm?

Comment: This is _not_ division, but splitting a decimal that is longer than suits a 32-bit integer into a hi and a low part using floating point arithmetics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made a new version of the algorithm's expanation to answer to the comments.
**New version**

As input we have a 64bit integer `v` represented as a string of decimal digits. We need to pack it into the [two's complement format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). The result has two parts `h` and `l` (high and low 32bit parts of a 64bit integer)

How to do it?

`v` = `h`*2^32 + `l`. It means that `h` is how many `whole` 2^32 contains `v`: `h` =floor( `v`/2^32). And `l` is the remainded part: `l` = `v` % `2^32`. We need to calculate them.

We need a data type to make calculation. On PHP we have `float` data type. It has [a mantissa of 52 bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). The mantissa can represent an integer in a range from 0 to 4*10^15 plus something (and the almost same range in the negative direction). `float` can represent the biggest range of numbers on 32bit PHP platform. So it is the best choise to make calculations.

We need to select a `divider` to split `v` because we cannot fit 64bit it into 52bit mantissa of `float`. Let split it into 2 parts `hi` and `lo`. `lo` conatains a number represented by 13 low decimal digits of `v`, and `hi` represented a number of another parts: `v` = `hi`*10^13 + `lo`. (*later we explain why `10^13` is selected* )

`hi` contains `h1` = `hi` * floor(10^13/2^32) times of 2^32. But the reminder (remainder means `hi` * (10^13%2^32) )  together with `lo` also can contain some 2^32. Let's count it: `h2` = `q` = floor(`hi`*(10^13%2^32) + `lo`)/2^32. And `h` = `h1` + `h2`.

Let's introduce m = `hi`*(10^13%2^32) + `lo`. `l` = `m` - `q`*2^32. Now we have the both parts `h` and `l`.

Why we selected `10^13`? We need to: 
1. Fit all numbers during calculations into 52bits
2. Get an integer (not a rational number) from `10^13 / 2^32` ( = 2328) to not get an error. 10^13 fits into that best.

**Old version**
This code packs a given number `v` into two 32-bits `h` and `l` parts using float point arithmetics.

The author of the code chose `10^13` as a divider to fit parts of `v` into 52bit mantissa of [double-precision floating-point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) without loss of significant bits (`2^51` is greater than `10^13`).

Explanation of the algorithm:

1. The given number `v` is divided into two parts by `10^13`:

   - `v = hi * 10^13 + lo`
2. Then the high part of the resulting number is calcualted:

   - `h = (10^13 / 2^32) * hi + (m / 2^32)`
   - where `m = lo + hi * (10^32 % 2^32)`
   - Here we calculate how many `2^32` contains in the given number `v` to fill high part `h` of the resulting 64bit integer. The tricky part is `m`. We need it to add the remainded 'amount' from `hi` to `lo` and calcualte how many `2^32` it contains.
3. `l` is actually calcualted as modulo:

   - `l = m % 2^32`.

Should this algorithm be rewritten? I believe it should be rewritten in a more clear way. I'd also check it on the loss of significant bits after multiplication of floats.

Comment: Can he choose as divider, for example, 10^16? Or 10^2? And I don't understand what really "h" is? High 32 bit? But why it calculated in this way?

Comment: 1. Yes, h is high 32 bits and l is low 32 bits. 2. The divider must be selected in a way to fit all operands and intermediate results of the algorithm into available double-precision floating-point format without loss of any signifiacnt bits. You can choose any number with which the condition will be satisfied. But because the  format of 'v' is decimal, you have to use a power of 10 for the divider, to split 'v'.

Comment: Why it calculates in this way? 1. It is logical to use a data format with the largest number of bits (or bits in mantissa for floting point numbers)  for processing of not representable on the platform big numbers. In PHP on 32bit platforms it's float. 2. It works.

Comment: I cannot understand method of calculation with modulo of 10^13 mod 2^32. Can you explain it?

Comment: I've tried to explain it in another way. I'd recommend to solve this task by yourself to understand the details. There are other ways to solve the problem certainly exist, and you may find even a better way. Be sure that you have good understanding of double-precision floating-point and two's complement data formats.

Comment: Okay, can you link me to some documentation (I've googled a lot but didn't found anything) or explain, what exactly IS 10^13 mod 2^32 in this calculation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72027/discussion-between-guy-fawkes-and-den).